# R script from command line

Tags: r, command-line

I wanted to run this example script: http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912 from Windows command line. So I opened the command line and typed `Rscript tryCatch.R 1`. However, I keep getting the error message `Error: R not found`. I did set the PATH environment variable as `C:\Programme\R\R-3.0.1\bin`. If I just type `R.exe`, it does start `R`, but it cannot find the packages that are to be loaded at start (e.g. `package 'utils' in options<"defaultPackages"> was not found`). I guess I have to set another path to the libraries somewhere, but I haven't got any idea where to do this.

UPDATE: After explicitly typing `PATH C:\Programme\R\R-3.0.1\bin` (rather than just adding this to the value of the environment variable PATH) it seems that `R` is found. However, a new problem occurs: `In normalizePath<path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork>: path[2] = "C:/Programme/R/R-3.0.1/library": Access denied`, the same than for the `methods` library. Then: `Calls: .First ... library -> .getRequiredPackages2 -> library -> normalizePath Execution stopped`. I'm using Windows 7 and I do have administrator rights.

Comment: Try using `R CMD BATCH tryCatch.R 1`. You may have to alter the script to accept the command line arguments (if so I will post an full answer but I am curious to know if this works first)

Comment: @SimonO101 Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately I get the same error message (`Error: R not found`).

Comment: You might want to look at http://batchfiles.googlecode.com .  Look at `R.bat`. e.g. `R.bat script myscript.R`, which is automatic but requires a reasonably standard installation or the `RPathSet.bat` alternative which is a flexible batch file in which you edit the variables and then run it prior to running R to set up your environment variables.    There is a pdf that comes with it that documents it.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks for your suggestion, I'll have a look at this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out that it was a language-specific problem on Windows 7, similar to what is described here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-May/276932.html

After changing `PATH` to `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin` the script is properly executed from the command prompt.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Comment: thank you! To note we point the PATH variable at the `\bin` folder rather than directly targeting the `.exe` file

Answer (score 7):

`Rscript` is very handy (`R CMD BATCH`  is the old way to ) specially under windows, But generally under I create a batch file to avoid all path's headache.

For example say launcher.bat:

```
@echo off
C:
PATH C:\Programme\R\R-3.0.1\bin;%path%
cd PATH_TO_YOUR_RSCRIPT
Rscript tryCatch.R 1
pause
```

And open a console(using cmd) , go where you have stored your launcher.bat and launch it. Or from the R cosnole using `shell`:

```
shell('path_to_launcher\launcher.bat')
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that's a good idea. Based on the content of your launcher-file, I've tried to explicitly define the `PATH`, which brought me one step forward, but still doesn't work properly. Once I'll get this fixed, I will try to run batch files.

Comment: @AnjaM I don'understand why do you mean by explicitly defining PATH? What do you have as error.

Comment: I've updated my original question and described the new error there. By explicitly defining PATH I mean really writing `PATH C:\Programme\R\R-3.0.1\bin` in the command line before typing `Rscript tryCatch.R 1` (the way you do it in your launcher-file). Previously, I just added the path to the PATH environment variable in Windows and thought this would be enough.

Comment: Try first toi execute the script from R using `source` . Once you get it works, the method should work.

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you so much for sharing

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem under windows 7, apparently, when setting environment variables>user variables the path is not added into the PATH, so the user must add this path in system variables > PATH
at the end just add the path to your .EXE files and voila.